# moving DocumentID from closed to open

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The Table I'm working in is `FD_Documents` inside this table we have a lot of columns but I only want to focus on the ones I need.

`DocTypeID`,`File_Number`

Now Documents are either open or finalized, now the open files ID is `a372c985` and the finalized files ID is `4614bc4e`

Now what I need to do is if file Number has a file in Finalized document type all the open files must be changed to Finalized as well.

For the life of me, I have tried a few methods and its just not working.

Example below.

```
DocTypeID,           file number
a372c985 (open)        14/21548
a372c985 (open)        14/21548
a372c985 (open)        14/21548
4614bc4e (Finalized)   14/21548
```

Result

```
DocTypeID,               file number
a372c985 (Finalized)        14/21548
a372c985 (Finalized)        14/21548
a372c985 (Finalized)        14/21548
4614bc4e (Finalized)        14/21548
```

Comment: When do you want the "update to Finalized" done? As soon as a Finalized row is added for the file number?

Comment: Is the content of your column the complete string `4614bc4e (Finalized)`?

Comment: Share your try.! you wanted this as a trigger or script or procedure

Comment: Hi All, appologies for only responding now. @Zoff Dino, yes as soon as there is a Finalized File Added.

Comment: @Anand a trigger will be great, but I script will do as well.

Comment: Did you try my answer with update?

Comment: Hi @Anand, your scrip does not seem correct? There is only one table FD_Documents, so why would i need to join another table, and Document type is a372c985, 4614bc4e? and not open, and finalized. I hope my question was clear for everyone?

Comment: Hi this is a self join with same table (so no another table).Replace will only replace the part of your documenttype column.

Comment: HI @Anand, please check the code below, does this look correct to you? it seems to give me an error on the join part

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

```
UPDATE a
SET    a.docid = Replace(a.docid, 'open', 'finalized')
FROM   tab a
       JOIN tab b
         ON a.filenum = b.filenum
            AND b.docid LIKE '%finalized%'
```

Your query updated

```
UPDATE a
SET    a.DocTypeID = '4614bc4e'
FROM   FD_Documents a
       JOIN FD_Documents b
         ON a.FD_0F273F09 = b.FD_0F273F09
            AND b.DocTypeID LIKE '%4614bc4e%'
```

I thought you want the exact 'finalized' word in there.

Comment: `UPDATE FD_Documents
SET    FD_Documents.DocTypeID = Replace(FD_Documents.DocTypeID, 'a372c985', '4614bc4e')
FROM   FD_Documents
       JOIN FD_Documents
         ON FD_0F273F09 = FD_0F273F09
            AND FD_Documents.DocTypeID LIKE '%4614bc4e%' `

Comment: no I just need to to change the Docid from Open to finalized once the finalized ID is there.

Comment: Yes i understand please try my updated answer. i just set DocTypeID = '4614bc4e' for filenumbers which have atleast one typeid is '4614bc4e'

Comment: Your try was correct except for not using alias where it is intended to.Cheers!

Comment: this script does not seem to work, every time I execute the script, it says 81320 rows affected? So its seems its not really changing anything in the database?